# JSON ObjectMapper in Flutter

Tags: json, dart, jsonserializer, objectmapper, flutter

I'd like to have **objects** serialized/deserialized from **JSON** in Flutter. I know I can use `JsonDecoder` from `json.dart` which gives me string-key based LinkedHashMap but I'm more interested in **ObjectMapper** approach so that I'm able to get **typed** response from deserialization.

I tried *redstone mapper* ([link](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/redstone_mapper)) and *exportable library* ([link](https://github.com/Leksat/dart-exportable)) with Flutter - both of which I'm not able to compile properly. I believe the problem is connected with the reflection library from Dart.

How can I achieve a working Object-Json Mapper using Flutter?

Sample code:

```
class A {

  @Field()
  String b;
}

import 'package:redstone_mapper/mapper.dart';
import 'package:redstone_mapper/mapper_factory.dart';

bootstrapMapper();
var desObj = decodeJson(jsonString, A);
```

Error:

```
Starting device daemon...
Running lib/main.dart on Nexus 5X...
Dart snapshot generator failed with exit code 254
Errors encountered while loading: 'dart:mirrors': error: line 1 pos 1: unexpected token 'Unhandled'
```

or this one:

```
Error detected in application source code:
error: Failed to load main script:
'package:redstone_mapper/mapper_factory.dart': error: line 4 pos 1: import of dart:mirrors with --enable-mirrors=false
import 'dart:mirrors';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with the libraries you tried is that they use `dart:mirrors`, which is not supported on Flutter.

You should try a library which uses codegen instead, for instance `built_value`: https://github.com/google/built_value.dart

Comment: Using this library is more than adding a simple `'import'` statement. Look up my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41251216/706387)

Answer (score 0):

As @HarryTerkelsen suggested there is **built_value** library from Google.

Serialization example can be found [here](https://medium.com/@davidmorgan_14314/darts-built-value-for-serialization-f5db9d0f4159#.s21taxqwe).
The downside is that *built_value* uses generated ***.g.dart** classes to create serializers so this library is not a simple "import & run" thing.

There is a sample project which showcases collection serialization. [Collection](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/blob/master/example/lib/collections.dart) and the [generated serializer](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/blob/master/example/lib/collections.g.dart).

In short - you need to run [this](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/blob/master/built_value_generator/tool/build.dart) to generate your serializers.

**EDIT:**

In the end I ended up writing simple serialization from scratch:

```
import 'dart:convert';

class ItemDescription {
  String tag;

  String name;

  static ItemDescription deserialize(String str) {
    JsonDecoder decoder = new JsonDecoder();
    var deserializedMap = decoder.convert(str);
    return deserialize(deserializedMap);
  }

  static ItemDescription deserializeMap(Map map) {
      ItemDescription description = new ItemDescription();
      description.name = map["name"];
      description.tag = map["symbol"];
      return description;
  }
}
```

Comment: Should the last line of the "deserialize" method be calling "deserializeMap", rather than itself?

Comment: Could you please add an example of how this would be used. Thanks in advance